# Between while and do in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have the following script that works fine:

```
!/bin/bash

a=12
while [ $a -gt 10 ]
do
    echo "$a"
    a=$(($a-1))
done
echo "done"
```

If I add line "echo something" above "do", I expect to see a syntax error in that line. It seems that `[ $a -gt 10 ]` is bypassed, and it becomes an infininte loop. How could that happen?

Comment: I guess one use-case of that is for `do-while` loops like in C, to check the condition after each iteration instead of before.

Answer (score 29):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands):

> **`while`**
>
> The syntax of the `while` command is:
>
> ```
> while test-commands; do consequent-commands;
> done
> ```
>
> Execute `consequent-commands` as long as `test-commands`
>   has an exit status of zero. The return status is the exit status of
>   the last command executed in `consequent-commands`, or zero if none
>   was executed.

Note: `test-commands`, *plural*. You can use multiple commands in the test, and so this is a perfectly valid loop, with the list of commands `[ $a -gt 10 ]; echo "$a"` as the test:

```
while [ $a -gt 10 ]
echo "$a"
do
   a=$(($a-1))
done
```

While the command `[ $a -gt 10 ]` may or may not fail, the `echo` will (almost) always succeed (unless it couldn't write the text, or some other error happened), so the *final* exit status of the test commands will always be success, and the loop will always be run.

Comment: Was this the case historically? With original UNIX v7 Bourne shell? Because if so, this would be revelatory - it would justify the choice of even having an additional `do` keyword in the first place, which otherwise seems like a weirdly redundant syntax choice.

Comment: At least in the seventh edition, yes. Here's the manpage for sh: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&arch=default&format=html talking about `while list [do list;] done` - interestingly the `do list` is marked as optional.

Comment: interestingly indeed,  it allows  `while`-`done`  to function as *do-while* in other languages,

Comment: Worth noting that this is not just `bash` specific behavior, [POSIX Shell Grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) specifies `while_clause     : While compound_list do_group`  and `compound_list` is specified as `newline_list term`. Tested that with `dash` on Debian-based system - works as well.

Answer (score 10):

From `man bash`:

> while list-1; do list-2; done
>   The while command continuously executes the list `list-2`
>   as long as the **last command** in the list `list-1`
>   returns an exit status of zero.

Which implies that a `list` could contain several commands, which it does (separated mostly by semicolons or newlines).

So, this works perfectly well:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=12

while 
    echo something
    echo "a before test =  $a"
    [ a -gt 10 ]
do
    echo "a after test =  $a"
    a=$(($a-1))
done
echo "done"
```

If the last command before the `do` is echo the exit code that the do receive is always true (0) and the loop becomes infinite.

Answer (score 4):

What the other answers here imply but don't explicitly say is that `[` is a built-in *command*, not a syntactical part of the `while` statement.

Try typing `help [` at your command line:

> `[`: `[` arg... `]`
>   Evaluate conditional expression.
>
> This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
>      be a literal `]`, to match the opening `[`.

So your script is *exactly* as:

```
!/bin/bash
a=12
while test $a -gt 10
do
  echo "$a"
  a=$(($a-1))
done
echo "done"
```

Which you change to:

```
!/bin/bash
a=12
while test $a -gt 10; echo something
do
  echo "$a"
  a=$(($a-1))
done
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 3):

As an example of this being taken to extremes, /usr/bin/tzselect typically has about 70 lines of code between the `while` and the `do` of the main loop which includes case statements and command substitution, and a single line between the `do` and the `done`.

Comment: ...and the single line is `:` (NOOP).

Comment: @AlexHajnal Interesting, in mine it's `coord=`.

Answer (score 2):

(as a note to complement other answers).

Using several commands in the condition list is often used to implement a loop similar to C's `do { blah; blah; } while (condition)`, that is where the condition is checked at the end of the loop so the code in the loop is run at least once.

In `sh`, you'd do it as:

```
while
  blah
  blah
  condition
do
  continue # or :
done
```

Though other approaches are possible like:

```
while true; do
  blah
  blah
  condition || break
done
```

Or:

```
continue=true
while "$continue"; do
  blah
  blah
  condition || continue=false
done
```

```
end=false
until "$end"; do
  blah
  blah
  condition || end=true
done
```